# Javascript array addition - all combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working through Coderbyte's array addition problem:

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function `ArrayAdditionI(arr)` take the array of numbers stored in `arr` and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false. For example: if `arr` contains `[4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]` the output should return true because `4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23`. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers.

I've come up with the solution below, but for some reason, cannot get the recursion to work. The code correctly identifies arrays where the remaining (non-largest) array elements exactly add up to the largest, but fail otherwise. Any suggestions?

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
  arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {return b-a});
  match = false;
  largest = arr.shift(arr[0]); 

  function test(a){
    if(eval(a.join("+"))==largest){
      match = true;
      return match}
    else {
      for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        newArr = a.slice();
        newArr.splice(i,1);
        return test(newArr);
      }
    }
  }

  test(arr);
  return match;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is evil. In almost all cases, it can be done without `eval`, and it will be faster and probably safer. Your

```
eval(a.join("+"))
```

can be written as

```
a.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; })
```

Now that that is out of the way: Your recursion works. Your *loop* doesn't. On the first pass of the loop, you already return the result, so the second, third etc. iteration of the loop in each recursion never happen.

Here's your code with minor changes:

```js
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
  arr.sort(function(a,b) {return b-a;});
  var largest = arr.shift(); 

  function test(a) {
    var sum = a.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    if (sum == largest) {
      return true;
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var newArr = a.slice();
        newArr.splice(i,1);
        if (test(newArr)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }

  return test(arr);
}
var result = ArrayAdditionI([4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This worked like a charm. Out of curiosity, why does the 'for' loop require instantiating 'var i = 0' vs. just 'i = 0'?

Comment: `for` doesn't. But you want `var i` somewhere in the function (doesn't matter where you put it, but the most readable and sensible would be at the top of the function; if it is only ever used as a loop counter, declaring it in the loop itself is usually acceptable). If you don't, then `i` "leaks out" and refers to a global variable; leaked global variables could have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this also by separating the two function and checking inside the `for loop` for `test` function:

```js
 function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
   arr.sort(function(a,b) {return b-a;});
   var largest = arr.shift(); 
   return test(arr,largest);
 }
  function test(a,largest) {
     if (eval(a.join("+")) == largest) {
       return true;
     } else {
       for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         var newArr = a.slice();
         newArr.splice(i,1);
         if (test(newArr,largest)) {//check if test returns true then only return from this method otherwise the last line will return false after whole execution
           return true;
         }
       }
       return false;
     }
   }
 var ar=[4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3];
 var result = ArrayAdditionI(ar);
 alert(result);
```